# Page Breaks in SSRS based on column values

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I have a report whose layout is as follows:

Region: NORTH

City         Net Sales            Profit/Loss(%)

NY             $1000                10%

--

--

Region: WEST

City         Net Sales            Profit/Loss(%)

SF           $3100                    5.6%

--

My requirement is that each Regions data should be shown on  a new page in SSRS (HTML as well as PDF). In other words , there would be as many pages as many regions there are.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Its simple if you use groups for the headers of the Regions. When you click on the table,  a list of icons appears on the left hand side of your table, showing what row you are on - for example, the detail row look like three horizontal lines. Right-click this and select "Insert group". This will create a row for the group header above the detail row and the group footer below the detail row. Group headers are good for titles and group footers are good for summing the values displayed in the details section.

Select the field to group on (Region) and check the "Page break at end" checkbox and you're done.

Comment: Thanks Chris for your reply. I tried the steps you suggested but could no get the desired output. Probably I'm missing a step or doing something wrong. The expected report output looks like this: http://i.imgur.com/9XRJh.png

Comment: That looks to me like what you are after - regions on different pages. You should have two groups - Region and Category. The outermost group (labelled 1) is for Region and is set to Page Break At End. The inner group (labelled 2) is for Category and is not set to Page Break At End. The query needs to be ordered by Region, Category, Subcategory. Should all work.